# Show time since post was made in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a comments system and would love to show the time since the post was made instead of the actual time the post was made.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Currently I pull the dateAdded

```
comment.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Don't use `DateTime.Now` in a web application.  The time zone of your server should be irrelevant.  Since you're storing the time a post was made, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

  ```
  comment.DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;
  ```

  Read:  [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)
- You can then subtract the time the post was made from the current time.

  ```
  TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - comment.DateAdded;
  ```
- Once you have a `TimeSpan` object, you can then use any of various methods and properties.

  ```
  // to get the total hours elapsed
  double hours = elapsed.TotalHours;

  // to get the total minutes elapsed
  double minutes = elapsed.TotalMinutes;

  // to get a string output of the elapsed time in the default format
  string s = elapsed.ToString();
  ```

  Be careful not to mistake the `Minutes` and `TotalMinutes` properties.  An elapsed time on 90 minutes will have `TotalMinutes == 90.0`, but `Hours == 1` and `Minutes == 30`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this HelperExtension

```
public static class TimeHelper{
public static string TimeSpanString(this DateTime date) {
            var Now = DateTime.Now-date; //better to use DateTime.UtcNow
            if(Now.Days>0){
                return Now.Days+" Days "+Now.Hours+" Hours "+Now.Minutes+" Minutes";
            }
            if (Now.Hours > 0)
            {
                return Now.Hours + " Hours " + Now.Minutes + " Minutes";
            }
            return  Now.Minutes + " Minutes";

        }
   }
```

Ex how to use it.

```
comment.DateAdded.TimeSpanString()
```